# Django CBV: How come my child method is not overriding my parent method?

Tags: python, django, oop, inheritance, django-class-based-views

I'm pretty new when it comes to python classes / django CBVs. I'm trying to have a method (print_test) from my child class override my parent class, but I can't get it to work. What am I doing wrong?

Below is my parent:

[image: parent]

This is my child:

[image: child]

I've tried a bunch of things but can't see to get it to work :/

Appreciate all help!

Comment: you have not shown how you use the classes so that we can figure out what might be wrong.   there should be code that instantiates an instance of your base or child class then calls print_test.

Comment: please update your question with that additinoal code

Comment: also, you seem to have things indented at the wrong levels in your example above.   your 593 line is out of place and not likely doing what you expect of it.

Comment: @LhasaDad thank you for responding. Maybe I'm misunderstanding something, but I thought for CBVs you don't actually instantiate instances (like a regular python class)...When I run the above code, the console prints "printing from parent" which tells me the method in the child class isn't overriding the one in the parent. But I'm not sure why it's not...

Comment: so,  a few things.  Django framework is finding your CBV and doing the instantiation for you.   you don't need the __init__ because the base django view class is doing anything that needs to be done with that.   to load the module that has your class in it,  python will  load and 'run' all the statements in your file.   your print is likely happening at module load time.  (it does not appear to be in a method in the image above so that is based on what I am currently seeing there.

Comment: The methods in the instance of the class will be called from DJango when it needs to render your view based on the request type (GET/PUT/DELETE/PATCH/etc....)  CBV's have a method for type of HTTP request.

Comment: FWIW,  your indentation in your parent class appears to not be correct.  line 114 is at the same level as defs of the functions and class attributes would be.  There are collapsed lines in your image so its tough to tell what is right or wrong but seems like something is off.

Comment: @LhasaDad thanks! I realized the issue. I posted the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized my folly...

The print_test() in the parent is tucked under the Post() method, but the print_test() method in the child class is not. So the scopes don't match up and thus it doesn't get overwritten.

When I moved the print_test() method in the parent class outside of the post(), it was overwritten!